# IEC 320 C8 wiring

Tags: power-supply, switches, wiring

I purchased [this](https://www.robotics.org.za/GDPS008?search=power%20switch) IEC 320 C8 AC socket switch for use in a power supply but I'm unable to find any sort of wiring diagram for it. Could someone please tell me which pin is which? It is not immediately obvious to me and googling did not turn up anything of use.

The adapter looks like this:

[image: Front]
[image: Back]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Wiring diagram. The fine neon indicator wires give a big clue.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQTsfv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Schematic diagram.*